# Jquery form submit URL Char limit

Tags: jquery, url, form-submit

Let's say, I have some hundred checkboxes, I select all and submit the form.

when I click on the button, I call a function, like,

```
function submitForm() {
    var allBoxes = .. //I have all the checkbox values here.
    $("#myform #allBoxes").val(allBoxes);
    $("#myform").submit();
}
```

Due to the Character limit In URL, I am not able to submit in IE. Working fine in Firefox.
Please suggest any alternative method to send limitless characters.

There is an alternative that if the button is named as submit, then it is fine. But I use different tiles, so I definitely need to use button.

Comment: Have you try with a POST request instead of a GET request ?

Comment: Damn, silly mistake, solved thanks buddy

Comment: Is there anything in jquery like $(..).post()? instead of <form method="post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsfot it's 2048. Since they invented the web and since IE forces this lower value, it's the lowest common denominator.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427

Under Firefox, I see people on the net reporting URLs of 0xFFFF working: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=155648&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a

Make POST request instead of a GET request !!